# JPA criteria predicate query combining Integer and String arguments

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm using JPA (EclipseLink flavor), framework JSF 2.0, querying a MySQL contacts table containing 4 fields:

```
contactId(int Pk), firstName (String), surname(String), countryId(int Foreign key)
```

The below code works fine if only using string arguments so that the user can enter as many or as few search strings as required (ie: if the search boxes are left blank, this is equivalent to select * and the entire dataset is returned).

The problem is in combining an integer argument (countryId) which is the foreign key that adds countries to the search criteria. After some research, I'm still having trouble understanding the right way to do this.

Does the integer need to be converted to a string representation within the searchContacts method? I gathered that JPA Criteria API provides typcasting but not type conversion methods? If so, What is the best way to include an integer in the below method and pass this integer into the predicateArray?

Thanks in advance!

```
public ListDataModel<Contacts> searchContacts(String firstname, String surName, int countryId) {

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Contacts> query = cb.createQuery(Contacts.class);
    Root<Contacts> cont = query.from(Contacts.class);
    query.select(cont);

    List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    Predicate firstnamePredicate, surnamePredicate, countryPredicate;


    if ((firstname != null) && (!(firstname.isEmpty()))) {
        firstnamePredicate = cb.like(cb.upper(cont.<String>get("firstname")), "%" + firstname.toUpperCase() + "%");
        predicateList.add(firstnamePredicate);
    }

    if ((surName != null) && (!(surName.isEmpty()))) {
        surnamePredicate = cb.like(cb.upper(cont.<String>get("surname")), "%" + surName.toUpperCase() + "%");
        predicateList.add(surnamePredicate);
    }
// here is where I am stuck and trying the solution suggested     by     meskobalazs, except I changed null to 0 since countryId is an integer
    if (countryId != 0) {
    countryPredicate = cb.equal(cont.<Integer>get("countryid"), countryId);
    predicateList.add(countryPredicate);
   }
    Predicate[] predicateArray = new Predicate[predicateList.size()];
    predicateList.toArray(predicateArray);
    query.where(predicateArray);
    ListDataModel<Contacts> contactList = new ListDataModel<Contacts>(em.createQuery(query).getResultList());

    return contactList;
}
```

}

The above caused the following EJB Exception:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6078] (Eclipse Persistence Services -     2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The class of the argument for the object comparison is incorrect. 
Expression: [
Base com.manaar.domains.Contacts] 
Mapping: [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToOneMapping[countryid]] 
Argument: [1]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Contacts )
at    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.incorrectClassForObjectComparison(QueryException.java:595)
at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.buildObjectJoinExpression(OneToOneMapping.java:287)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.RelationExpression.normalize(RelationExpression.java:803)
```

The countryid is an integer with a manyToOne mapping in the contacts entity to the country entity. The contacts entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contacts")
@XmlRootElement
public class Contacts implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "CONTACTSID")
private Integer contactsid;
@JoinColumn(name = "countryid", referencedColumnName = "COUNTRYID")
@ManyToOne
private Country countryid;
```

The country entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
@XmlRootElement

public class Country implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "COUNTRYID")
private Integer countryid;
@Size(max = 255)
@Column(name = "COUNTRYNAME")
private String countryname;
.....
```

Comment: Hi Jay, can u share your Contacts entity. its to find if your CountryId is integer or Entity of Country table. in addition also share the exception.

Comment: Hi Aj. Thanks for the response. I have included both contact and country entities in the main body and explanation of their relationship. I haven't included any exception because I was not even trying any correct method so I need to first understand the right concept through which to work. Please let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution for your predicate

The `Predicate` class is not typed (generic), so you don't need to collect different predicates any differently. This should work just fine:

```
if (countryId != null) {
    countryPredicate = cb.equal(cont.<Integer>get("countryid"), countryId);
    predicateList.add(countryPredicate);
}
```

---

## JPA canonical metamodels

This is just a suggestion, but you also might consider building the canonical metamodels for your entities (e.g. with Apache Dali), so you can `get` your fields in a typesafe manner.

Instead of

```
cont.<MyType>get("typeName")
```

you could write:

```
cont.get(_MyType.typeName)
```

This is especially useful, if you are refactoring your entities, because you might forget updating the Strings, but you can't forget updating your metamodels, because the code does not even compile otherwise.

---

## Updates

I have missed a few design problems with your entities. There are two possible solutions.

### Creating a new Entity field

The first one is creating an actual `Integer` field in `Contacts` and map it to the same field as `countryId`.

So you should rename the `Country` field to `country`, and create a new field.

```
@Column(name = "countryid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer countryId;

@JoinColumn(name = "countryid", referencedColumnName = "countryid")
@ManyToOne
private Country country;
```

After you do this, you are able to use my original solution.

### Using a Join

The second solution is using a `Join` in your query.

```
if (countryId != null) {
    Join<Contacts, Country> country = cont.join("countryid");
    countryPredicate = cb.equal(country.<Integer>get("countryId"), countryId);
    predicateList.add(countryPredicate);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful suggestions mesko. On your first suggestion I tried if(countryId !=0), as null would not work on integer. Unfortunately it produces an EJB Exception which I will post in the main body of the question. As for canonical metamodels, I would firstly like to master a basic way to add an integer argument according to your first suggestion.

Comment: Of course it would work with `Integer`. That is an object, do not confuse it with the `int` primitive.

Comment: I am also surprised that I'm getting a compile time error if I try to add if(countryId !=null), but no error if I state (countryId != 0). I have used null with Integer before and it works, but not in this case for some reason

Comment: I see now, the method is wrong, the third argument should be `Integer`.

Comment: OK sorry about my oversight. I fixed the third argument and the compile error is gone, but I still have the same EjbException

Comment: Oh, I see the reason, your variable names are unfortunately quite terrible. The `countryid` is actually a `Country`entity, and not an ID.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately it's an automatically generated code  by the Netbeans IDE (supposed to save me time). So country id is a foreign key in the contacts DB. So the trick is how to refer to this in the get  method for CountryPredicate to get the countryid.countryid, where the second countryid is the integer. This might be a matter of using the right SQL. Or maybe I should just change the countryid to country

Comment: OK I can't thank you enough! The second method worked and the Join was successful. I'm also going to try the first method but I know that will involve more configuration to change the mapping. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, the first one is more tedious coding-wise, but it saves a join, which is an expensive operation.

Comment: Well then it might be a better option because I have about 2 more foreign keys, for company and for sector. So my question on the first method is what would happen to the original Country countryid entity if the mapping is changed by a countryId integer? There would still be a need to preserve the Country entity in the ORM mapping right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70385/discussion-between-meskobalazs-and-jay-tai).